# Kivy, ScrollableLabel only black color with a big text

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I'm folowing [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/scrollable-label) tutorial to create a scrollable label, but using this example I get only a black screen with too many example.

The code is:

```
long_text = 'yay moo cow foo bar moo baa ' * 100

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollableLabel>:
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        text: root.text
''')

class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')

class ScrollApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScrollableLabel(text=long_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScrollApp().run()
```

That code works perfectly, but with I put the following on line `14` I get a black screen:

```
return ScrollableLabel(text=long_text * 26)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the texture containing the rendered text is too large for the gpu to work with (the exact limit depends on the machine).

The basic solution is to split the text into multiple Labels. The [ScrollLabel](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.scrolllabel) in Kivy garden does this automatically and efficiently, so you probably want to look at using that.

Comment: Thank you for helping me @inclement. But using this does not work.  Try this code on your machine: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kivy-garden/garden.scrolllabel/master/__init__.py. I only get a black screen.